# Debug heap/STL debugging equivalent for GCC?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc

I plan on using GCC more (Linux and Windows) and I was wondering if there's an equivalent of the MSVC [debug heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1%28VS.80%29.aspx)  and the [STL checks](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/02/26/stl-destructor-of-bugs.aspx) available for the GCC CRT and STL.

I already know about tools such as Valgrind, but I'm looking for something built in the libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with the debug heap and STL checks, but when I have memory problems in GCC on linux I use an environment variable called MALLOC_CHECK_ (from malloc(3)):

> Recent  versions  of Linux libc (later than 5.4.23) and GNU libc (2.x) include a
>       malloc  implementation  which  is  tunable  via  environment  variables.    When
>       MALLOC_CHECK_ is set, a special (less efficient) implementation is used which is
>       designed to be tolerant against simple errors, such as double  calls  of  free()
>       with the same argument, or overruns of a single byte (off-by-one bugs).  Not all
>       such errors can be protected against, however, and memory leaks can result.   If
>       MALLOC_CHECK_  is set to 0, any detected heap corruption is silently ignored; if
>       set to 1, a diagnostic is printed on stderr; if set  to  2,  abort()  is  called
>       immediately.   This  can  be  useful  because  otherwise a crash may happen much
>       later, and the true cause for the problem is then very hard to track down.

There is also Electric Fence which can help catch buffer overruns aborting as soon as the overrun / underrun happens.  See [libefence(3)](http://perens.com/FreeSoftware/ElectricFence/) for more information.

Comment: This is exactly what the Debug Heap does Peter, thanks! Do you happen to know if these checks are also done for new/delete?

Comment: It does in my implementation (operator delete, at least, seems to have an underlying call to free(), so it catches the double-free).  Electric Fence definitely catches buffer overruns with memory allocated by operator new.

Comment: Note that glibc 2.10 and 2.11 are buggy: MALLOC_CHECK_ can cause hang and crash multi-threaded programs.

Answer (score 3):

The STLport version of the standard library at http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlport/ has a debug mode, which I used to use, and which is recommended by Scott Meyers in Effective STL. I haven't used it for several years now however, so I can't vouch for the current state.

There is also a thread about GCC STL debugging [here](http://osdir.com/ml/gcc.libstdc++.devel/2002-04/msg00209.html), but I once again I can't vouch for the info it gives.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I would really prefer not to replace the STL, because I use 3rd party libraries that were built with the "standard" STL.

Comment: Unfortunately you'll have to use a different set of STL containers to get support for a debug STL even if you use a library implementation that comes from the same vendor as your regular library comes. I'm pretty sure there isn't really any 'debug STL' out there where the object don't change their layout if you're using the debug version. So IMHO you'll have to go and rebuild all components with the same version of the library and the same flags anyway.

Comment: As far as I know, MSVC has the debug STL features on by default, so the debug version of a library that uses the STL will use the debug features (assuming they didn't explicitly turn them off - which would make the lib incompatible with default MSVC projects).

I could make an effort and rebuild, but I would still like to use the classic STL if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used them, but I do know glibc has some capabilities for doing debugging of dynamically allocated memory. Here's a relevant manual entry http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Memory-Allocation.html#Memory-Allocation. "Unconstrained Allocation" has some information on various ways to hook the allocation functions and "Allocation Debugging" contains some information on glibc's abilitiy to trace allocations.

Personally, I think Valgrind is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Some heap debugging is available with efence/DUMA (even under MinGW)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for can be enabled by defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` before including any standard libraries.  I'm not sure what affects this will have if you can't use it consistently.  My default advice would be to be very careful.  Also I've heard that the debug checks can be a big performance hit.  So big that it may be unwise to always have it enabled for debug builds.